# heroku pg error using rails, saying type modifier is not allowed for "text"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

i get the error

```
PGError: ERROR:  type modifier is not allowed for type "text"
LINE 1: ...ng(255), "desc" character varying(255), "content" text(255),...
```

when i do a heroku run rake db:reset

i understand that postgresql needs an unlimited type for 'text' and in my latest migration file i have...

```
class ChangeLessonsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        change_table :lessons do |t|
            t.change        :content, :text, :limit => nil
        end
    end
end
```

i still keep getting the error though. any ideas why? i ran rake db:reset, rake db:migrate, and git push to make sure my local db changed. then i ran git heroku push and heroku run rake db:reset but i keep getting that error. am i missing something? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to leave off the `:limit` entirely:

```
class ChangeLessonsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        change_table :lessons do |t|
            t.change :content, :text
        end
    end
end
```

If that doesn't work then you could try separate up and down actions:

```
def up
    change_column :lessons, :content, :text
end
def down
    change_column :lessons, :content, :string
end
```

As an aside, if you're targeting PostgreSQL you should just use `:text` and forget about the `:string` (AKA `varchar`) column type, PostgreSQL treats them all the same internally. The only time you should bother with varchar/`:string` is when your data integrity requires a specific upper limit on the string size.

Comment: thank you. i winded up doing the latter. my heroku db:reset still didn't work nor did heroku db:migration. i had to....do a db:migration on my on local db, then do a heroku db:push